# Protractor: Return Repeater Count from Prototype

Tags: javascript, angularjs, count, repeater, protractor

I have this behavior which I can't understand:

```
Cart.prototype.getCouponsCount = function() {

    // Loop through all rows of coupons currently available in the cart
    ele.cartCouponsList.count().then(function(count) {

        console.log("Amount of items in cart:", count);
        return count;
    });
};
```

When called like this:

```
var Cart = require("../../../../lib/cartlib");
var cart = new Cart();

expect(cart.getCouponsCount()).toBe(2);
```

Returns `undefined`, but in console I can see the correct coupon amount being printed. So it's just not returning the count back.

Similarly I have this working for the `getText()` method, therefore why I can't understand why the `count()` method would behave differently.

Working method:

```
Cart.prototype.getEvent = function(row) {

    var cartHistory = new Cart();
    var parent = cartHistory.getCartCoupon(row);

    var child = parent.element(by.binding("selection.event.name"))
        .getText().then(function(e) {

            console.log(e);
            return e;
        });
};
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no return* from the function, add it:

```
Cart.prototype.getCouponsCount = function() {

    // HERE 
    return ele.cartCouponsList.count().then(function(count) {

        console.log("Amount of items in cart:", count);
        return count;
    });
};
```

Comment: Ouch... should've tried that out... nonetheless thanks for the help :)